# How to show JSON data with Associate Array Key?

Tags: php, drupal-modules, json

in the below code, i used simple $key,$value but i want to use that code with associate array key. Then how can i do? Please help.

```
<?php
function custom_table_page_display() {

  $jsonData = '{ "User":"John", "Age":22, "Country":"India" }';
  $phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);
  $rows = array();

  foreach($phpArray as $key => $value)
  {
        $rows[] = $key;
        $value1[]=$value;
  }
  $header=$rows;
  $value11[]=$value1;
    $output = theme('table',array('header'=>$header,'rows' => $value11));

  return $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: `Then how can i do?` do what?

Comment: if i say in 1 word is that... how to use array_keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);
```

The second argument says whether to return an associative array or object for a JSON object. By default it returns an object.

You can replace your `foreach` loop with:

```
$rows = array_keys($phpArray);
$value1 = array_values($phpArray);
```

For the data you gave in the comment below, you would do:

```
$rows = array_keys($phpArray['Class'][0]);
$values = array_map('array_values', $phpArray['Class']);
```

`$values` will then be a 2-dimensional array of values:

```
[ [ "John", 22, "India" ],
  [ "Sam", 23, "Argentina" ],
  [ "John", 22, "Algeria" ]
]
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/TjYNZy)

Comment: Call `array_keys($phpArray)`. What's the problem?

Comment: its working.. thanx... @Barmar.. 1 more query... can i insert multiple records... with array_keys...

Comment: You need to make the JSON an array of objects. Then you'll need to loop over them. They should all have the same keys, so you only need to do `array_keys($phpArray[0])` to get the keys.

Comment: i tried but not got correct result... 
may you please help...
if i have data something like this..

$jsonData = '{ "Class" :
                   [{"User":"John", "Age":22, "Country":"India"}],
                   [{"User":"Sam", "Age":23, "Country":"Argentina"}],
                   [{"User":"John", "Age":22, "Country":"Algeria"}]
              }';
then how to do...

Comment: its working but only key shows... value not shown... m i write correct...

'{ "Class" :
                   [{"User":"John", "Age":22, "Country":"India"},
                   {"User":"Sam", "Age":23, "Country":"Argentina"},
                   {"User":"John", "Age":22, "Country":"Algeria"}]
              }';

Comment: i agree with you... when i debug the code through print_r(); it shows correct result.. but in the output... i got only key not value...

Comment: $phpArray = json_decode($jsonData,true);
  $rows = array_keys($phpArray['Class'][0]);
  $values = array_map('array_values', $phpArray['Class']);
  $header=$rows;
  $value11[]=$values;
  $output = theme('table',array('header'=>$header,'rows' => $value11));
  return $output;   i do this to got output... but :(

Comment: if i want to store the json part in another place then how can i include the json part.. @Barmar

Comment: What do you mean by "the json part"? If you want to store `$jsonData`, just assign it to another variable.

Comment: Means i want to store JSON data in another file i.e. test.json... then how to fetch/call the JSON data... @Barmar

Comment: Use `file_put_contents("test.json", json_encode($phpArray))` to save it, and `json_decode(file_get_contents("test.json"))` to retrieve it.

Comment: for for fetching file... it must to give write full url.../opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal7JSON/sites/all/modules/custom_module/custom_module.module...

Comment: my code is some thing like this... now where to change.... function custom_module_page_callback() 
{

$jsonData = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal7JSON/sites/all/modules/custom_module/';


$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData,true);


$header = array_keys($phpArray['Class'][0]);

$rows = array_map('array_values', $phpArray['Class']);

$output= theme('table', array('header' => $header,'rows' => $rows));
return $output;
}


?>

Comment: I'm just giving an example of the general structure, not showing the exact code. Of course you need to adjust it to the specific situation. I don't know your filesystem structure.

Comment: in localhost..  '/opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal7JSON/sites/all/modules/custom_module/custom_module.module'... here my file is stored & test.json is also stored in same place...

Comment: Look, I'm not going to write your program for you. I've explained the general principles, you should be able to apply them to your application without having to ask me about every line.